# Module '"events"' has no exported member 'Listener' when using jssip in angular 14

Tags: typescript, jssip

I am getting following error in my angular project when using jssip library.

Error: node_modules/jssip/lib/RTCSession.d.ts:1:23 - error TS2305: Module '"events"' has no exported member 'Listener'.

I am using angular 14 and typescript version 4.8.4

Any help on this would be much appreciated?

I tried uninstalling current version and using previous versions but still getting same issue. tried till jssip version 3.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding **skipLibCheck=true** in tsconfig.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).